# Existence of open and dense subset of $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ with measure between $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to study abit of measure theory. I would appreciate it if someone could explain me step by step on how to deal with this kind of task.

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ a set with lebesgue measure $1$.

How does one show that for any $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$ there exists an open and dense subset of $A $ with lebesgue measure $\alpha$?

Comment: Do you know about the [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set)?

Comment: @Bungo fat cantor set is actually closed, and has empty interior. So we need to consider its complement. Also, since OP asked about $\Bbb R^n$, we may need to spend a little extra effort in constructing  the fat cantor set in higher dimenisons.

Comment: @Vim Yes, my comment was meant to be a hint, not a solution :-)

Comment: The claim is false as stated: $A$ might not contain any open subsets at all, yet have large measure (e.g. $A$ = the irrationals).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Weird, somehow I misread it as seeking an open dense subset of $[0,1]$ with measure $\alpha$. Maybe it should be open relative to $A$?

Comment: I know the Cantor set but havent heard the name fat cantor set yet